# Set TEmbeddedWB to ViewOnly mode?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, twebbrowser, tembeddedwb

Is it possible to set TEmbeddedWB to a **ViewOnly** mode? I.e., the user cannot click on links, the mouse pointer does not change when hovering over a link, etc.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. But there's no magic switch for this. It will consist of wrapping all event handlers to be able to stop certain things from working.

Comment: @JerryDodge What do you mean with "wrapping all event handlers"?

Comment: I mean intercept all the events which are triggered when activity happens, and stopping it from further action. This is a complex subject though, I'm just trying to point you in the right direction.